# Python: checking for duplicates

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to make a function that rolls dice until all dice rolls are equal, removing the most frequent die from the next roll. What I'm struggling with is finding an easy way to check if the list only contains the same number. I've managed to get as far as getting the same numbers on all dice, but it turns into an infinite loop. Any suggestions as to how I can check if a list is just the same number, so I can use that as a condition to break the loop?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to post your code?

Comment: Hi @Jakob! Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example :: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the description. "removing the most frequent die from the next roll" – How can a die be frequent? If this is about the most frequent number, how can a number be removed? Is there actually some point to the "dice rolling" or is it just the *context* in which you have the specific problem of unique elements, which doesn't actually depend on the dice rolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to cast your list to a [set()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_set.asp).

As sets can only have unique members, the cast will remove any duplicates. So a list of all the same number, when cast to a set will only have one element.

```
>>> l1 = [1,4,1,1,1]
>>> len(set(l1))
2
>>> l2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
>>> len(set(l2))
1
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't quote understand the function of set() until now, those solved everything :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code for checking if a given list has only one unique value in it.

```py
if len(set(your_list)) == 1:
   break
```